# Can the master theorem be applied to $T(n) = 5T\left(\frac{N}{2}\right) + (n^2) \lg (n)$?

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations

I am reading CLRS for algorithms.

One of the exercises in the book is to solve recurrence

$$T(n) = 4T\left(\frac{N}{2}\right) + n^2 \lg( n)$$

and I am sure that master theorem cannot be applied.
This is so because it turns out that $\log_2 4  = 2$

But what if we change the $a$ to the, say $5$.

Now $\log_2 5 = 2.32$

and indeed this is higher polynomial power than that of $f(n)$.

So should we say that case $1$ of the master theorem applies?

I am little confused because I do not have confidence whether the fraction part of the polynomial will make a significantly large difference to say the function is bound from above asymptotically.

A little elaboration of why or why not would help

Comment: In case you haven't heard of it, Akra-Bazzi is a generalization which covers even more cases.

Comment: @Chris, I have not studied it in detail. Can you elaborate how does it apply to this particular problem and can I apply masters theorem by that generalization? I am sure if we can apply it, then it will be first case, and so complexity will Big-Theta(n^log 5 base 2)

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) on the theorem covers both its hypotheses and its application. (Clearly in your case the hypotheses are satisfied.)